# Besides UI, any other pros that Blue Ocean for Jenkins has comparing with Jenkins pipeline plugin?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-blueocean

Any advantage of using Blue Ocean instead of Jenkins pipeline plugin? I can't find much information about this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blue Ocean is good for visualisation of stages and highlighting errors in the logs. Although, Classic view has more standard features (for example - `Build with Parameters` that can be crucial)